# Create and iterate through a list of numbers in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, list, loops, curl

I am trying to use cURL on about 200 select ports, and I would prefer to not have to do each one at the same time. I am also trying to learn the basics of Bash.

What I am trying to do is create a list of numbers and then iterate through each of those numbers. Here is what I have:

```
Ports={1,5,7,10,12}
for port in $Ports
    do
        $echo "Port $port"
        curl "URL:$port"
    done
```

Is this possible to do or am I thinking too high level? Thank you!

Comment: Are the ports sequential? And if so what is the range?

Comment: @Darragh it would seem not `Ports={1,5,7,10,12}`.

Comment: Yeah, actually, good point.

Comment: @Darragh they are not sequential, there are 30 different ports between 1 and 1000

Comment: Okay, when you said "I want to create a list of numbers" I inferred that you wanted to generate a list of numbers. But if I understand correctly now, you have this list already, right? And you want to know how to format it so it can be iterated over?

Comment: @Darragh correct. Cyrus's method of passing in the port numbers into a string worked perfectly. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

Ports="1 5 7 10 12"
for port in $Ports; do
  echo "Port $port"
  curl "URL:$port"
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize you could pass in a string like that

Comment: Perfect. Can I ask a related question? `for port in $ports` works, but not `for port in "1 5 7 10 12"` (at least on my machine). Can you explain why, this is something I've wondered about.

Comment: `for port in "1 5 7 10 12"` provides only a single string, not 5 separate strings, to be assigned to `port`. `for port in $Ports`, after expansion, is equivalent to `for port in 1 5 7 10 12`.